# Swift: Encryption of a file or plain text

Tags: objective-c, swift, security, encryption

Hello i'm about to write an app that enables me to store remote files on iPhone's local disk to make the data permanent in a file and manipulate with it. But i have a question about this. I have no idea about encrypting data by the way.

So if any iPhone hacker crack the prone with jailbreak and access my local file? In this situation, i want to use **Encryption**. But i'm missing something. My json files contains long plain texts like 100,000 words. So if i apply the **CryptoSwift** library which is on Github now, using the AES and NSDATA my computer is stuck to encrypt it.

```
    let plain = "mylongtextfromfile".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let key: Array<UInt8> = [0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00]
    let iv: Array<UInt8> = AES.randomIV(AES.blockSize)
    let encrypted: NSData = try! plain!.encrypt(ChaCha20(key: key, iv: iv)!)
    print(encrypted)
    let decrypted: NSData = try! encrypted.decrypt(ChaCha20(key: key, iv: iv)!)

    let string1 = NSString(data: decrypted, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    print(string1)
```

I also noticed that Apple does not want to use of another encryption libraries unlike its built-in APIs. The Itunnes connect policy requires an extended verification process of the app. 
I want to ask you experts that what i must to do. I do not want to user to interact with any mobile service-back-end, API or server for downloading the words and query them once the users want to use the words each time.

What i need to use to keep the process fast. Actually is there any way to only encrypt file itself unless the data in. Or what is the mistakes i'm facing.

sincelery,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if any iPhone hacker crack the prone with jailbreak and access my local file?

Yes. This is true, and there is nothing effective you can do about. You can create some layers of obfuscation. You can slow down attackers by a few hours. With sufficient resources and an ongoing team of security experts you may be able to slow down an attacker for longer. But if Apple with control of every piece of the ecosystem, and extensive and expert resources dedicated to it, can't stop attackers from jailbreaking the phone, you have no hope, especially, if as you say, you know nothing about encryption.

That is not to say that there is nothing at all you can do; it just won't be very effective, so don't spend tons of time on it. You must assume that if your data is of any significant value, attackers will extract it. You must design your system and business model to be resilient to that. Or you must employ an ongoing team to mitigate attacks, like Apple or Blizzard do.

So what can you do that will be simple and provide some kind of obfuscation, even if it's pretty ineffective? As you appear to be trying to do, encrypt it against a hard-coded key. It won't stop anyone who knows what they're doing, but it'll keep away some people, and that's about as good as you can do.

CryptoSwift is a nice library, written by a smart guy, but it's very low level, and assumes you know what you're doing. This is not the kind of tool you want to be using for this. You want something that does all the work for you. I have one, [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor). It has the advantage of being very simple, cross-platform, and only using Apple crypto primitives. There is also [libSodium](https://github.com/mochtu/libsodium-ios) which is even more portable and is a more powerful format, but doesn't use Apple's primitives.

The important thing to look for is something that offers an encryption *format*, not just crypto primitives. It is very challenging to build a secure format out of primitives. Don't attempt it without first studying how it's done.

If you do want to move forward with CryptoSwift, then you'll need to explain more precisely what is going wrong. When you say "my computer is stuck," what precisely is happening?

Comment: The code that i mentioned on the Q, i dont know but i assuma it encrypt my NSData Object which is contains plain text. My problem is if i want to encrypt some plain text which contains by like 100K or 1M words inside. The encryption process takes long and leaves the computer with frozen state.

Comment: The encryption process takes long and leaves the computer with frozen state. I'm assuming the stack maybe does not fit all the data in. But as you say i'm on a view that low level of the Library causes some exploits maybe or slow performance. I only want to ask you that if i use Apple's build-in encryption APIs or RNCryptor and if i want to encrpyt my file contains 100K or 1M word populated files, how long it takes or maybe can i encrypt the file in 3-5 secs for good UX? is it possible? thanks!

Comment: as you say, maybe this idea keeps some people who does not know what they're doing away for a while.

Comment: You don't want to encrypt or decrypt that much data on the main queue. You don't even want to read that much data from disk on the main queue. You'll need to do this on a background queue. But you should be able to get this done in much less than 3-5 seconds. CryptoSwift was never designed to be fast. It was built as a curiosity to explore algorithms that Apple doesn't provide and to do it in pure Swift. https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/issues/5#issuecomment-53379391

Comment: Understood. Thanks. Is there any solution do you recommend for a fast security solution to keep my file secure?

Comment: I know a lot of people who use RNCryptor this way with a random password. This isn't what RNCryptor is designed for, but it's quick to implement, and will generally stop most people who don't know how to use a debugger. (Stopping someone who knows how to use a debugger is a much bigger investment.)